# Query Limit Restriction in Looker Studio: How to Modify and Set Limits for Queries

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have attempted to run SQL queries in Looker Studio to generate reports based on a revenue table with specific criteria. However, despite my efforts, the queries seem to be running with a default limit of 20 million, which is not aligned with my reporting needs.

I expected to find a way to modify or set the query limit in Looker Studio to accurately reflect the desired constraints.

Below is the sample query that running while accessing the report in Looker studio

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    clmn2_, 
    clmn1_, 
    SUM(clmn5_) AS clmn100000_ 
  FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        t0.app_name AS clmn2_, 
        t0.revenue AS clmn5_, t0.transaction_date AS clmn1_ 
      FROM table_name t0
  ) WHERE ((clmn1_ >= DATE "2023-11-01") 
      AND (clmn1_ <= DATE "2023-11-07") 
      AND (clmn2_ <> "null")
    )
  ) GROUP BY clmn2_, clmn1_
) LIMIT 20000000
```

I am seeking guidance on the appropriate steps to achieve this and ensure that the queries return results within the specified limitations.